# Sketchflow removing a component

Tags: sketchflow

I have a screen and I have a section where a component screen is inserted. I have a cancel button on the component screen and was wondering if it is possible to remove the component from the main screen using the cancel button. Is this at all possible?

So, once the component is shown, cancel on the component screen removes it so the first screen is shown again.

JD

Ps. I am using Blend 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my first screen I have a default state (which is that state before the component screen is added). On the cancel button of the component screen, I set the ActivateStateAction.TargetProperty to the main screen and set the TargetState to default. Now when I press the cancel button, the first screen is shown.

This is what I want. Just wonder if there is a better way to do this using screens but from what I can see I cannot nest a screen inside another screen.

JD.